# The meaning of "heels long past when others would have considered it advisable"

Tags: meaning

The passage below is from **Being Mortal** by **Atul Gawande**.

**I met her grandmother Alice Hobson, who was seventy-seven at the time. She struck me as spirited and independent minded. She never tried to disguise her age... She wore simple, neatly pressed blouses and dresses, a bit of lipstick, and *heels long past when others would have considered it advisabl*e.**

Here, I can not figure out the meaning of the *italicized* phrases.
Under the context I just assume that grandmother was wearing heels worn out with usage. Am I right? If not, can you tell me what does it mean?

Comment: She wore "heels" (high-heel shoes) when most people her age would have found this dangerous (or at least uncomfortable).

Comment: This is not exactly about English but more about life. As one gets older, ankle strength doesn't get better and the consequences of even a simple fall are more serious. So heels, presumably high heeled shoes often worn by women, are not advised as one gets older, but this woman is still wearing them despite her advanced age.

Answer (score 1):

Retirement Age of Fancy Shoes  This writer says **mid forties**!

“Anything too high or too crazy should be avoided,” DeMartino says. [everydayhealth.com](https://www.everydayhealth.com/skin-beauty/top-10-items-youre-old-wear/)